# How do you validate wikipedia URLs like these in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Url: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Tax

Is not being validated with Regex:

```
function isValidURL($url) {
 return preg_match('|^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9-]+\.(.[a-z0-9-]+)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

So the purpose of this is: We have a whole lot of urls embedded inside posts (forum) - we want to create a script which will basically keep track of which urls are still good. For this we need to extract the URLs from the posts and create a database - which can be checked at intervals for their status codes.

Comment: What does "validate" mean? You have a URL, and you want to see whether it matches the regex? And it doesn't match the regex? And you're asking us to debug your regex? – Why don't you parse the URL using a URL-parser (e.g. `parse_url()`) and verify its parts, e.g. that the Host component is wikipedia.org etc. *Much* simpler than maintaining of gobbledygook regex.

Comment: Here is what your regex should look like: `(http(s)?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9\-]+\.([.a-z0-9-]+)+(:[0-9]+)?(\/.*)?`

Comment: I am extracting the urls from the post strings and creating a database of these urls. Checking the status using curl to make sure they are not 404s.
The regex is just to check the validity of the urls which are extracted from the post string.

Comment: @MariaDeleva - your regex worked perfectly. Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

To matching this URL You can use this:

```
^https?\:\/\/([\w\.]+)wikipedia.org\/wiki\/([\w]+\_?)+
```

This only match URL, but to validate which url's are still good (if I understand right it means active)... this is not job for a regex.

Comment: No, the regex is just to extract the urls. Using curl to check the status.
Need something that would be able to identify and extract all kinds of urls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative regex for most URLs:

```
(?<![@\w])(((http|https)(:\/\/))?([\w\-_]{2,})(([\.])([\w\-_]*)){1,})([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])
```

You can experiment with regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: this is for generic urls, not wikipedia